# where to find a windsor controller factory for mvc 2 ? There is no mvccontrib.castle.dll anymore o_O

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, mvccontrib

I was using WindsorControllerFactory from mvccontrib.castle lib until now, after i migrated to mvc 2 it doesn't work anymore, I've downloaded the latest mvccontrib release and no factories in there

Comment: there is one in mvccontib.castel 1.5 rc1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to download [MVCContrib.Extras.release.zip](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/releases). It has the controller factories and the rest of the stuff.